# Counting $1$'s in a specific finite $(0,1)$-matrix.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, symmetric-matrices

Let $A(n)$ be a finite square $n \times n$ matrix with entries $a_{ij}=1$ if $i$ and $j$ are each prime and $i+j$ is even otherwise it equals $0$. For an example consider $A(5)$:

$$A(5)= \text{ }\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0&1\\
0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0&1\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

I write $|A(n)|$ to denote the number of $1$'s in $A(n)$. I also denote the ratio of $1$'s to the total number of entries in $A(n)$ as $t(n)$. Explicitly we can write $|A(n)|$ as $\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}$ and $t(n)=n^{{\above 1.5 pt }2}|A(n)|$. I can compute $|A(n)|$ and $t(n)$ for small values of $n$. The table below shows some initial values for $n=1$ to $19$:

\begin{array}{| l | l | l | l |l|}
\hline
n & |A(n)| & t(n) \\ \hline
1 & 0 & 0.00000000000 \\ 
\color{red}{2} & \color{red}{1} & \color{red}{0.25000000000} \\ 
\color{red}{3} & \color{red}{2} & \color{red}{0.22222222222} \\ 
4 & 2 & 0.12500000000 \\ 
\color{red}{5} & \color{red}{5} & \color{red}{0.20000000000} \\ 
6 & 5 & 0.13888888888 \\ 
\color{red}{7} & \color{red}{10} & \color{red}{0.20408163265} \\ 
8 & 10 & 0.15625000000 \\ 
9 & 10 & 0.12345679012 \\ 
10 & 10 & 0.10000000000 \\ 
\color{red}{11} & \color{red}{17} & \color{red}{0.14049586777} \\ 
12 & 17 & 0.11805555556 \\ 
\color{red}{13} & \color{red}{26} & 0.15384615385 \\ 
14 & 26 & 0.13265306122 \\ 
15 & 26 & 0.11555555556 \\ 
16 & 26 & 0.10156250000 \\ 
\color{red}{17} & \color{red}{37} & \color{red}{0.12802768166} \\ 
18 & 37 & 0.11419753086 \\ 
\color{red}{19} & \color{red}{50} & \color{red}{0.13850415512} \\ 
    \hline
    \end{array}

First, via inspection it appears that $|A(n)|$ can be written as a square-plus-one. In particular if $q$ is the $n$-th prime then $|A(q)|=(n-1)^2+1$. For example $19$ is the the $8$-th prime number and $|A(19)|=(8-1)^2+1=7^2+1=49+1=50$. Second it also appears that $t(n)<{1 \above 1.5pt 4}$ whenever $n \neq 2$.

> ***Question 1:*** Can we find a formula for $|A(n)|$ ?

and

> ***Question 2:*** Can we compute the $\lim_{n\to \infty}t(n)$ ?

Here is what I think I know and here was my approach. Concerning ***Question 1***. If we let $^t$ denote the transpose map then surely $A(n)^t=A(n)$, in particular $A(n)$ is symmetric. We have the following decomposition of $A(n)$. Let $D^-,D$ and $D^+$ count the number of $1$'s in those entries below the diagonal, on the diagonal and above the diagonal of $A(n)$ respectively. Since $A(n)$ is symmetric we know that $D^-=D^+$ and so we can write $|A(n)|=2D^-+D$. Now assume $q$ is the $n$-th prime. Under the assumption that $|A(q)|=(n-1)^2+1$ whenever $q$ is the $n$-the prime is true, we have $2D^-+D=(n-1)^2+1$. On the other hand if $\pi(x)$ is the [prime counting function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function) then $D=\pi(q)$. To see this recall that the sum of two primes is an even number and so the entry $a_{ii}$ would be assigned the value $1$ for every $i$ that is prime and less than or equal to $q$. This is best illustrated by looking at the example $A(5)$ above and noting that $a_{22}, a_{33}$ and $a_{55}$ are each assigned the value $1$. Note, if $q$ is the $n$-th the prime then $\pi(q)=n$. Putting all this together I suspect we have that if $q$ is the $n$-th prime then possibly:

$$|A(q)|=2D^-+\pi(q)=(\pi(q)-1)^2+1$$

If the above expressions are true then: 
\begin{align} \\
2D^-+\pi(q) &= (\pi(q)-1)^2+1 \\
&=\pi(q)^2-2\pi(q)+2 \\
2D^- &= \pi(q)^2-3\pi(q)+2 \\
2D^- &= (\pi(q)-1)(\pi(q)-2)\\
\end{align}

The last expression would imply that $D^-={(\pi(q)-1)(\pi(q)-2) \above 1.5pt 2}$. Finally we can if we want write $$|A(q)|=(\pi(q)-1)(\pi(q)-2)+\pi(q)$$ The above expressions are speculative and it could be the patterns in the table will change as $n$ grows. I did all the counting by hands and hopefully there are no errors. On ***Question 2*** maybe the $\lim_{n \to \infty}t(n)=0$. See the crude graph below. 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you increase the size $n$ of the square matrix to a composite $n+1$, the entire last row and column are zero, which means that $|A(n)|$ does not increase. Thus, the only thing we need to focus on is what happens if we increase from a prime number $p(k)$ to the next prime $p(k+1)$.

There are $\pi(p(k+1))=k+1$ total primes beneath $p(k+1)$, meaning that there are a total of $(k+1)^2$ pairs of primes, but because the sum of 2 and any other prime is odd, 2 does not form pairs with any other primes except with itself, and there are only $k^2+1$ pairs of primes for $|A(p(k+1))$|. For any composite $n$ between $p(k + 1)$ and $p(k+2)$, the number remains the same as for n = p(k+1): $|A(n)| = |A(\pi(n))|=(\pi(n)-1)^2+1$

Thus, $|A(n)| = (\pi(n)-1)^2+1$

As for $t(n)$, $$t(n)=\frac{|A(n)|}{n^2}=\frac{(\pi(n)-1)^2+1}{n^2}$$.

We do not know for sure what the growth rate of the prime number function is, but it is most definitely less than n, and is conjectured to be $$\pi(n) \sim \frac{n}{\ln{n}}.$$ Thus, as we take the limit of $t(n)$ to infinity, we should get zero, as the denominator would grow much faster than the numerator.

Comment: You defintely answered question1 ! Although I would suggest rewriting your solution to be consistent with how my problem is written so that others can follow your answer more readily. Also I would explictly write out how excluding the column indexed by the number $2$ reduces the number of $1$'s possible in $|A (n)|$.

Comment: Will do so thanks